# SQL finding students who attended tuesday class, ascending order by address

Tags: mysql, sql

need to find who attended class on Tuesday and list all of student information, order by address.

(NEW TO SQL) sorry for the rough question.

I have 3 tables -

1. student
2. tegroup
3. tegroup_list

I require all information from student who have attended class on Tuesday.

```
student
student_num [PK]    student_name    address    sex
```

```
tegroup_list
(tegroup_idc[FK]    student_num[FK]) [combined are PK]
```

```
tegroup
tegroup_idc [PK]    unit_id    day
```

the value **Tuesday** is contained in column **day** in the table **tegroup**

my expected results in a search query is,

```
Student_num    Student_name    address    sex
1              kyle            1 street   M
```

(ascending) ORDER BY address **&** results only listing students who attended class on Tuesday.

Hopefully I've redeemed myself with the edit.

(P.s) I'm using workbench.

```
SELECT 
student_num, 
student, 
address, sex
from student
where student_num
order by address
IN (select student_num from tegroup_list where tegroup_idc =
(select tutegroup_idc from tegroup where day LIKE '%tuesday%'));
```

This was my answer, just to update!

```
SELECT distinct s.student_num, s.address, s.student_name, s.sex
from student as s
INNER JOIN tegroup_list
INNER JOIN tegroup
where day LIKE 'tue_%'
order by s.address;
```

thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: ORDER BY should be at the end, i.e. after IN subquery.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: no problem philpxy, Thanks for sharing!
I'll make sure to read up on "How to ask"

Comment: Hi. Please post answers as answer posts, not edits to question posts. (Also we ask to not put greetings, thanks, etc in posts.) You can roll this back by clicking on 'edit' then on 'rollback' of the last version. If this edit is just a copy of another answer, just click on its check mark to show it helped you most, like you did, and don't post another copy of it. We can see the check. Closed posts have answering blocked, but maybe not for answers by the asker. [answer] [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a script like below-

```
SELECT 
S.student_num, 
S.student, 
S.address, 
S.sex
FROM student S
INNER JOIN tegroup_list TL ON S.student_num = TL.student_num
INNER JOIN tegroup T ON TL.tegroup_idc = T.tegroup_idc
WHERE T.day LIKE '%tuesday%'
ORDER BY S.address
```

Answer (score -1):

The only obvious problem with your query is that the `ORDER BY` clause is in the wrong place. Move it to the end of the query.

```
select student_num, student, address, sex
from student
where student_num in 
(
  select student_num 
  from tegroup_list 
  where tegroup_idc = (select tutegroup_idc from tegroup where day like '%tuesday%')
)
order by address;
```

This assumes that there is only one `tegroup` on Tuesday. If there can be more, change `where tegroup_idc =` to `where tegroup_idc in`. And it is likely you don't need a `LIKE` expression, as a Tuesday is probably just 'Tuesday' and not something like 'on Tuesday, the day before Wednesday', so `where day = 'Tuesday'` should suffice.